# Is it ever appropriate to use a 'return {value}' in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've written a couple of express apps in Node, and I have a shameful gap in my knowledge.  Please, go easy on me.

Is it ever appropriate to use this traditional format for functions in Node.js?

```
function isGreaterThanZero ( val ){
    return val > 0; 
}
```

or should you always use a callback?

```
function isGreaterThanZero (val, cb){
    if (val > 0) {cb(true);}
    else {cb(false);}
}
```

The async nature of Node.js has my brain turned inside-out, and I'm questioning everything.

Comment: Simple answer: you need a callback when the function itself needs to pass a callback to something else. (Not 100% always, but it's a basic rule of thumb.) If you're doing something like converting a string to a  standard phone number, then no you don't need a callback because that's simple in-line computation.

Comment: If its not async why use callbacks? This just increases your stack depth and makes code harder to read.

Comment: What about an array.filter()?  Is that asynchronous since it requires a callback?  I would assume so, since the async library provides its own 'replacement' version.

Comment: No, that's not asynchronous. The callback in that case is simply to pass along the condition used to test each element in the Array. The only way to pass around functionality is in a function.

Comment: ...you can know it's not async by putting a `console.log()` inside the `.filter()` callback, and then one after. If it had been async, the one after would be invoked before the ones inside the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it's appropriate

**This is for synchronous code**

```
function isGreaterThanZero(val){
    return val > 0; 
}
```

In lay terms, you'll use synchronous functions when there's nothing to wait for. You'll use synchronous functions outside of the exceptional cases noted below

For in-memory operations, things like basic calculations, string manipulations, array append, etc, you can use synchronous functions.

**However,** some synchronous functions do use callbacks but they're more for mapping or filtering purposes. In the comments, I see you asked about `arr.filter`. Other functions like `arr.forEach`, `arr.map`, or `arr.reduce` take callbacks but they're **not** implicitly asynchronous. In this case, the callback function is just used to augment the behavior of the called function.

---

**This is for asynchronous code**

```
function isGreaterThanZeroAsync(val, cb){
  // some long process...
  cb(val > 0);
}
```

You'll use asynchronous functions when you have something to wait for. Generally that's network, file system, or database access. An async function will allow you function to return (exit) immediately (as sync functions do) but the callback will get the value as soon as it's ready.

**Here's a little async demo**

```
function demoAsync(cb) {
  console.log("demo start");
  setTimeout(function() {
    cb("hello world");
  }, 1000);
}

console.log("init");
demoAsync(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
  console.log("demo done");
});
console.log("init done");
```

**Output**

```
init
demo start
init done
// 1000 ms later...
hello world
demo done
```

**Why is this important?**

You get `"init"`, `"demo start`", and `"init done`" immediately. This demonstrates your *program can continue* while we're waiting for the demo to finish.

After `1000 ms` we see `"hello world"` and `"demo done"`.

Hooray! Everything happens in order.

Comment: I want to add that, for synchronous function, you ALWAYS should return values to not confuse other developers (or yourself) into thinking it was an sync operation. Than can lead to trouble.

Comment: @maček -- I wanted to thank you again for this.  Your explanation has lead me to becoming way more comfortable in Node and JS in general.  That question had plagued me for a while.